# Unreal Engine - Error al pasar de 4.19 a 4.20

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine

Tengo una copia del proyecto en la 4.17 que es donde empece a progamarlo, lo he ido pasando hasta la 4.19, el problema que al pasar de la 4.19 a la 4.20 me da unos errores que he probado a volver a coger el proyecto de la 4.17 y pasarlo a 4.19 y no me los da, puede darse a un cambio de interpretacion por parte de unreal pero no le encuentro la solucion, os comparto una captura del fallo y el codigo donde se encuentra.

[image: esta imagen representa el fallo]

Cualquier cosa que me falte decidmela cuando empece el proyecto no sabia c++ nada y use una plantilla pagada, empece a editar por bp, ahora que se java voy a empezar con c++ pero aun no se como funciona bien del todo y menos con unreal engine
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta borrar esta lista de archivos antes de hacer el update a la nueva version de Unreal Engine.

- *.xcodeproj
- *.xcworkspace
- *.sln
- *.suo
- *.opensdf
- *.sdf
- *.VC.db
- *.VC.opendb

Esta lista de carpetas:

- Binaries/*
- Plugins/*
- Intermediate/*
- Build/*

Cuando abras el proyecto estos se deberian volver a generar, el archivo de .sln, se va a generar cuando abras el proyecto con VS.